# Split the distinct values in a list separated by a comma

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a pandas dataframe

| index | DevType | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Developer, back-end | 3086 |
| 2 | Developer, back-end;Developer, front-end;Devel... | 2227 |
| 3 | Developer, back-end;Developer, full-stack | 1476 |
| 4 | Developer, front-end | 1401 |
| 5 | Developer, back-end;Developer, desktop or ente... | 605 |
| 6 | Developer, embedded applications or devices | 433 |

This is achieved by applying `.value_counts()` on a column, as you can see Developer is repeated as it is combined with others answers, from this dataframe I want to create a possiblewords list to count number of each of them repeated later on.

I tried the code below to find the unique values first

```
unqlist=list(df_new['DevType'].unique())
```

by using 'unqlist' i tried to seperate distinct words using below code

```
possiblewords=[]
for word in unqlist:
    print(word.split(','))
   possiblewords.append(word)
```

it's not working

Comment: You can use `set` to get all unique elements in a list. If you want all words separate you have to modify the input list. `set(devtype_list)` gives the result. It is not clear how you want to change the list elements for your unique list, but I assume you want to split the elements? But then what?

Comment: please go through this data set once https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey in DevType column multiple answers are pushed into a single cell, i want the count of unique values, i tried set but multiple answers are combined in quotes so its not working

Comment: No you should provide data, an example and what you would like as output. I am not going to download files for everyone who want help.

Comment: As @3DspatialUser has said, what you intend to do with a `distinct()` method can be achieved using sets. There's something bugging me though: there are both `,` and `;` in the different strings. Do you only want the colons as separators, or the semicolons too? I actually think the semicolons are the separators in your examples. Also, there's a `nan` in your example list. Is that right? Shouldn't it be `None`, or are we perhaps dealing with a numpy or pandas data structure?

Comment: Yea , i framed the question in a wrong way ill delete it and ask again thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Pandas [`.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split on comma and semicolon, put the result in a numpy array.  Then, use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get the unique words after flatten from 2D array to 1D array, as follows:

```
import numpy as np

list_all = df_new['DevType'].str.split(r'(?:,|;)\s*').dropna().to_numpy()

list_unique = np.unique(sum(list_all, []))
```

**Result:**

```
print(list_unique)

['Devel...' 'Developer' 'back-end' 'desktop or ente...'
 'embedded applications or devices' 'front-end' 'full-stack']
```

Comment: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list` i am getting this error on line `list_unique = np.unique(sum(list_all, []))`

Comment: is that error because of NaN?

Comment: @KrishnaGannamaneni  Yes, probably it's because of `NaN`.

Comment: @KrishnaGannamaneni  Let me customize the code to handle this.

Comment: yea I dropped Nan rows, and its working like a charm, thank you so much your help is invaluable to me, working on this for five hours writing loops :(

Comment: @KrishnaGannamaneni  Great!  Pleased to help!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

`list(set(''.join(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), devtype_list)).split(',')))`

Answer (score 0):

You can split the list with `,` and `;` as delimiter to separate the unique words.

```
def split_words(x):
    return sum(list(map(lambda y: y.split(";"), x.split(','))), [])

devtype_list = ['Developer, desktop or enterprise applications;Developer, full-stack', 'Developer, full-stack;Developer, mobile', 'nan', 'Designer;Developer, front-end;Developer, mobile', 'Developer, back-end;Developer, front-end;Developer, QA or test;DevOps specialist', 'Developer, back-end;Developer, desktop or enterprise applications;Developer, game or graphics', 'Developer, full-stack', 'Database administrator;']
newlist = list(set(sum(list(map(lambda x: split_words(x), devtype_list)), [])))
newlist = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), newlist))

for unique_word in newlist:
    print(unique_word)
```

Result:

```
Developer
front-end

Designer
desktop or enterprise applications
game or graphics
mobile
Database administrator
QA or test
DevOps specialist
nan
back-end
full-stack
```